# Not able to see Kendo Grid the output

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was working to use Kendo Grid in asp.net mvc4.Here is the code written in contrller and view.But i am not getting the Kendo Grid in output.Can anyone help me with this?
I have used ADO.NET entity model to form class called Contacts to connect to the database
and in the controller i have converted the data coming from Contacts class to json.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller

 {

        public PersonaEntities db = new PersonaEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Getjsondata()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Hello World";
            JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult();
            var Contacts = db.Contacts.ToList();
            jsonResult.Data = Contacts;
            return Json(jsonResult,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Then i have tried in the view to display kendo grid by giving its datasource as controller action method.But I am not getting the output as kendo grid.

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Getjsondata";
}

<h2>Getjsondata</h2>
<link href="~/Content/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: { read: { url: "Home/Getjsondata", dataType: "json" } },
            schema: {
                data: function (data) {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        })


        $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "id",
                    title: "id"
                },
                {
                    field: "fname",
                    title: "fname"
                },
                {
                    field: "lname",
                    title: "lname"
                },
                {
                    field: "phone",
                    title: "phone"
                }


            ]
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="Grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Json` method encapsulated the data into a `JsonResult already`. Your reposonse is double-wrapped. Pass the data directly into the `Json` method.

You'll need two actions, one for the static view and one for the `JsonResult`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GridView()
    {
        return this.View();
    }

    public JsonResult Getjsondata()
    {
        var Contacts = db.Contacts.ToList();
        return Json(Contacts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

For the view, you need a `GridView.cshtml`:

```
@* css and js imports omitted *@
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '@Url.Action("Getjsondata")',
                        type: 'GET', // should be POST, though
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    type: "json",
                    model: {
                        id: "id",
                        fields: {
                            'id' : { type: 'number', editable: false},
                            'fname': { type: 'string' },
                            'lname': { type: 'string' },
                            'phone': { type: 'string' }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "id",
                    title: "id"
                },
                {
                    field: "fname",
                    title: "fname"
                },
                {
                    field: "lname",
                    title: "lname"
                },
                {
                    field: "phone",
                    title: "phone"
                }
            ]
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="Grid"></div>
```

The url of the page is `~/Home/GridView`. When you open the page, the controller only returns the static page `GridView.cshtml`. Once the page is loaded on the client side (your browser), the JavaScript code will run and make an AJAX request to the `~/Home/Getjsondata` action to load the data for the kendo grid.

Comment: But it gives me output like:[{"id":"1","fname":"sunil     ","lname":"vora","phone":756865},{"id":"2","fname":"karthik   ","lname":"krishna","phone":356486}] I am not able to get kendo grid in the output.

Comment: That is how the data is supposed to look. Try to omit the schema part of your dataSource declaration, but declare the type (GET) in the read part. Also check for JavaScript errors.

Comment: I have already posted the code for view can you suggest me where to make changes since i am a beginner.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually on debugging i found that i get result in json format from controller itself.It does not go to the view to display output.Can you suggest me what to do?

Comment: See my edit. Disclaimer: I haven't tried it, so there may be little errors.

Comment: I tried by making the changes but error comes in javascript.It says that kendogrid is not a function.The error comes when it executes  $("#Grid").kendoGrid says "Uncaught Typeerror:Undefined is not a function.

Comment: Is the kendo js library properly imported?

Comment: ya i think because when i had imported Kendo UI Professional package and tried the same demo in simple html,it worked.How to check whether it is properly imported or not?

Comment: Your browser's debugging tool should tell you which scripts are loaded. Also you did insert the link and script tags from your original code, right? I just omitted those, but they're still necessary.

Comment: The browser google chrome shows all scripts are loaded.I did insert link and script from my original code,but still same error.Can you figure it out whats wrong?

Comment: Do you actually have a Kendo UI Professional (Trial) license? Kendo Grid isn't part of Kendo UI Core. I just set up a trial project with Kendo Core 2014.2.716. There is no kendo.all, hence no grid. If you do have a pro version, make sure that jQuery is only loaded once. For testing you can set `@Layout = null;` in the view to make sure that no other js libraries are loaded in the ViewStart or Layout.

Comment: yes i know i have installed Kendo Grid Professional from Nuget Packages.Can you tell me where to make changes to ensure jquery is loaded once.The jquery-1.9.1.js file gets loaded in the Scripts folder in browser but does not gets loaded in kendo folder which is inside scripts folder.On debugging i found that it does not execute script at all of jquery in view just goes to (Url.Action("Getjsondata") and jumps from there.

Comment: Hey @bstenzel didnt see you for a while?

Comment: Can you give me link where i can get a demo for using Kendo grid in ASP.NET MVC4?Also see my comment regarding current problem and guide me if anything can be done in it to see kendo grid in output

Answer (score 0):

I found out that i was loading the script jquery.js manually which i think gets loaded by default in browser.Also i found that scripts and css files need to be mentioned only in shared layout file and not necessary to mention it in view.

jquery asp.net-mvc